# How to make IntelliJ Scala plugin run the unit test, or how to teach IntelliJ that a file is a unit test code?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ/Scala plugin, how can I run the Scala test code?

```
class TestFile extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter {
  test ("simple") {
```

I'm not sure exactly what happened, but I remember IntelliJ/Scala plugin automatically showed me a "run" menu with the right click, but I see nothing about the run menu. Is there any setup change to teach this file is Scala test file that can be executed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the source (especially on test class name or test name) opens up a menu that shows the run menu.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure that it won't run as test

Comment: @Marco Acierno: It runs as 'test'. The two menus are the same with the same shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Find the directory where all your tests are (if you are using Maven directory structure that would be src/test/scala) right click on it and choose "Mark directory as"-> "Test Sources Root". This would tell IntelliJ that the directory contains test and would make it offer to run tests in the right click menu of files

Comment: It was already set as a test sources root, so I'm not sure exactly what happened. However, I restarted the IntelliJ, and it looks like working fine.